# Doing CRUD on XML using id attributes in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm a LAMP guy and ended up working this small news module for an asp.net site, which I am having some difficulty with.  I basically am adding and deleting elements via AJAX based on the id.  Before, I had it working based on the the index of a set of elements, but would have issues deleting, since the index would change in the xml file and not on the page (since I am using ajax).

Here is the rundown

news.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<news>
  <article id="1">
    <title>Red Shield Environmental implements the PARCSuite system</title>
    <story>Add stuff here</story>
  </article>
  <article id="2">
    <title>Catalyst Paper selects PARCSuite for its Mill-Wide Process...</title>
    <story>Add stuff here</story>
  </article>
  <article id="3">
    <title>Weyerhaeuser uses Capstone Technology to provide Control...</title>
    <story>Add stuff here</story>
  </article>
</news>
```

Page sending del request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.del').click(function () {
                var obj = $(this);
                var id = obj.attr('rel');
                $.post('add-news-item.aspx',
                    { id: id },
                    function () {
                        obj.parent().next().remove();
                        obj.parent().remove();
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
    <a class="del" rel="1">...</a>
    <a class="del" rel="1">...</a>
    <a class="del" rel="1">...</a>
```

My functions

```
protected void addEntry(string title, string story)
    {
        XmlDocument news = new XmlDocument();
        news.Load(Server.MapPath("../news.xml"));

        XmlAttributeCollection ids = news.Attributes;
        //Create a new node
        XmlElement newelement = news.CreateElement("article");
        XmlElement xmlTitle = news.CreateElement("title");
        XmlElement xmlStory = news.CreateElement("story");

        XmlAttribute id = ids[0];
        int myId = int.Parse(id.Value + 1);
        id.Value = ""+myId;
        newelement.SetAttributeNode(id);
        xmlTitle.InnerText = this.TitleBox.Text.Trim();
        xmlStory.InnerText = this.StoryBox.Text.Trim();


        newelement.AppendChild(xmlTitle);
        newelement.AppendChild(xmlStory);

        news.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newelement);

        news.Save(Server.MapPath("../news.xml"));
    }

    protected void deleteEntry(int selectIndex)
    {
        XmlDocument news = new XmlDocument();
        news.Load(Server.MapPath("../news.xml"));

        XmlNode xmlnode = news.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(selectIndex);
        xmlnode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(xmlnode);
        news.Save(Server.MapPath("../news.xml"));
    }
```

I haven't updated deleteEntry() and you can see, I was using the array index but need to delete the article element based on the article id being passed.  And when adding an entry, I need to set the id to the last elements id + 1.  Yes, I know SQL would be 100 times easier, but I don't have access so...  help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to XML should make this a lot simpler. Here would be the equivalent of what you are trying:

```
        public void AddEntry(string title, string story)
        {
            var newElement = new XElement("article", new XElement("title", title), new XElement("story", story));                
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(testXml);
            var maxId = doc.Descendants("article").Attributes("id").Max(x => int.Parse(x.Value));
            newElement.Add(new XAttribute("id", ++maxId));
            doc.Descendants("news").First().Add(newElement);
            //save the document
        }

        public void DeleteEntry(int selectIndex)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(testXml);
            doc.Descendants("article").Where(x => int.Parse(x.Attribute("id").Value) == selectIndex).Remove();
            //save the document
        }
```

Based on the size of your xml file and the number of requests, you may want to look into other approaches than loading the document, and saving it for each call to add and delete.

**EDIT**: Note that you would need to add null checks to the above code...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace LinqToXML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int ch;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the operation you want to execute");

                Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to show previous record");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to add new record");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 3 to delete record");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 4 to update record");

                Record RecordObject = new Record();

                int UserChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (UserChoice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        RecordObject.ShowRecord();

                        break;

                    case 2:
                        RecordObject.AddRecord();

                        break;

                    case 3:
                        RecordObject.DeleteRecord();

                        break;

                    case 4:
                        RecordObject.UpdateRecord();

                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option");
                        break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\tDo you Want to CONTINUE?\n\t1.YES\n\t2.NO");
                ch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (ch == 1);
        }
    }

    class Info
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public int StudentAge { get; set; }
        public string StudentCity { get; set; }
    }

    class Record
    {
        string fileAddress = @"C:\XML.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        public void ShowRecord()
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileAddress))
            {
                string line;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileAddress))
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No record exist");
            }
        }

        public void AddRecord()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Name :");
            string StuName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student Age :");
            int StuAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student City :");
            string StuCity = Console.ReadLine();

            Info InfoObj = new Info();

            InfoObj.StudentName = StuName;
            InfoObj.StudentAge = StuAge;
            InfoObj.StudentCity = StuCity;


            FileStream FileStreamObj = null;

            if (File.Exists(fileAddress))
            {
                FileStreamObj = new FileStream(fileAddress, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                FileStreamObj.Close();

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(fileAddress);

                XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//students/student");
                int nodeCount = nodes.Count;
                nodeCount++;


                XmlNodeList students = doc.SelectNodes("//students");
                foreach (XmlNode student in students)
                {

                    XmlNode parentNode = doc.CreateElement("student");

                    XmlAttribute attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
                    attribute.Value = nodeCount.ToString();
                    parentNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                    student.AppendChild(parentNode);

                    XmlNode studentName = doc.CreateElement("studentName");
                    studentName.InnerText = StuName;
                    parentNode.AppendChild(studentName);

                    XmlNode studentAge = doc.CreateElement("studentAge");
                    studentAge.InnerText = StuAge.ToString();
                    parentNode.AppendChild(studentAge);

                    XmlNode studentCity = doc.CreateElement("studentCity");
                    studentCity.InnerText = StuCity;
                    parentNode.AppendChild(studentCity);

                    doc.Save(fileAddress);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                FileStreamObj = new FileStream(fileAddress, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                FileStreamObj.Close();

                int StudentId = 1;

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                XmlNode rootNode = doc.CreateElement("students");
                doc.AppendChild(rootNode);

                XmlNode parentNode = doc.CreateElement("student");
                XmlAttribute attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("id");
                attribute.Value = StudentId.ToString();
                parentNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
                rootNode.AppendChild(parentNode);

                XmlNode studentName = doc.CreateElement("studentName");
                studentName.InnerText = StuName;
                parentNode.AppendChild(studentName);

                XmlNode studentAge = doc.CreateElement("studentAge");
                studentAge.InnerText = StuAge.ToString();
                parentNode.AppendChild(studentAge);

                XmlNode studentCity = doc.CreateElement("studentCity");
                studentCity.InnerText = StuCity;
                parentNode.AppendChild(studentCity);

                doc.Save(fileAddress);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateRecord()
        {
            doc.Load(fileAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter ID of the record you want to update");
            int InputChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Info infoObj = new Info();

            XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode nodeElement = element.SelectSingleNode("student[@id='" + InputChoice + "']");

            if (nodeElement == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Record doesn't exist");
            }
            else
            {
                string oldName = nodeElement.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                string oldAge = nodeElement.ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
                string oldCity = nodeElement.ChildNodes[2].InnerText;

                infoObj.StudentName = oldName;
                infoObj.StudentAge = Convert.ToInt32(oldAge);
                infoObj.StudentCity = oldCity;

                Console.WriteLine("Old Values are:\n\tName: " + infoObj.StudentName + "\n\tAge" + infoObj.StudentAge + " \n\tCity" + infoObj.StudentCity + "");

                Console.WriteLine("Enter new name");
                string newName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter new Age");
                int newAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter new city");
                string newCity = Console.ReadLine();

                infoObj.StudentName = newName;
                infoObj.StudentAge = newAge;
                infoObj.StudentCity = newCity;

                nodeElement.ChildNodes[0].InnerText = infoObj.StudentName;
                nodeElement.ChildNodes[1].InnerText = infoObj.StudentAge.ToString();
                nodeElement.ChildNodes[2].InnerText = infoObj.StudentCity;

                doc.Save(fileAddress);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteRecord()
        {
            doc.Load(fileAddress);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Id you want to delete");
            string inputValue = Console.ReadLine();

            XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode nodeElement = element.SelectSingleNode("student[@id='" + inputValue + "']");
            if (nodeElement == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Record doesn't exist");
            }
            else
            {
                element.RemoveChild(nodeElement);
                doc.Save(fileAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully deleted");
            }

        }
    }

}
```